# total days in Arrears calculation

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

guys i have problem with one old SP which calculates total days late when the costumer is late with the payments of an instalment
it goes like this:

```
#total days paid#     #1st inst days due#   #2nd inst days due#  #total days#
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

   0                        1                        0               1
   0                        2                        0               2
   0                        3                        0               3
   0                        4                        0               4
   0                        30                       0               30
   0                        31                       1               31  
   0                        32                       2               32
  32                         0                       3               35
```

so the procedure calculates (total days paid) + max of the days due

```
0+32 =32
32+3 =35
etc
```

and makes mistakes whenever the costumer is latemore then 30 days 
its should always increment by 1 and not overlap the calculations
can anyone think of a quick way to fix this without over writhing the whole thing

Comment: perhaps show the stored proc? might be useful?

Comment: on the thing you showed us, there is no real evidence that #2nd is ever added to anything, apart from maybe the last row.  If I had to guess, I'd speculate that the there is some logic involving CASE statements, but it really is impossible to know without seeing it, and maybe easy to see the prob if the query is revealed.

Comment: I think I get it, for your column   [(total days paid) + max of the days due] (whatever that formula is), change it to ' [(total days paid) + max of the days due] + CASE WHEN  [(total days paid) + max of the days due] >= 30 then 1 ELSE 0 END

Comment: so from above, just repeat the original formula in the CASE statement to ask if the calculated value is >=30, then if it is, you add 1 - with no rewrite of any other bits of the proc - my stuff in square brackets [...] represents your existing formula, which you don't put in brackets (or only round ones)

Answer (score 0):

so you have an existing formula for calculating #total days#, if you can locate the final place where that is returned, it could be a formula or a field name, let's call that (...) because we don't know what it is here, you can change it to

```
(...) + CASE WHEN (...) >= 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS '#total days#'
```